# Display image before form launch - Compact Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-mobile, compact-framework, loading

I have a Windows Mobile application where in the Main method I show the Main form:

```
[MTAThread]
static void Main()
{
    new MainForm().ShowDialog();
}
```

When the program starts I see the the typical animation loading:

[image]

Instead of this animation I want to see an image (full screen), how can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you can find a complete sample on how to embedd a splash screen to your .NETCF application.
[.NET Compact Framework Sample: Splash Screen](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22845)
Don't be confused that link points to the .exe, this sample is made as an installer but as the end result you'll see the code itself.

Answer (score 2):

One unfortunate thing about the CF SLR is that it shows that wait cursor down in the bowels when it starts JITting and loading classes.  There's no way to get rid of it.  You can create your own splash screen, but keep in mind that it won't show until the framework is loaded enough to display it unless it's a separate app.  Even with a separate splash screen, that wait cursor will still be there, so it's not an "instead" like you want, but an "also".

Comment: Is there a way to display programmatically this "wait cursor"?

Comment: Yes, set `Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor`